# Does the Bot Framework allow defining logic to run when returning to a dialog from a Scorable?

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm working in a scenario where I have a dialog similar to this simplified example:

```
public class ExampleDialog : IDialog<bool> {
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"{What is your name?");

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var message = await result;
        // do some validation of the answer and log it off somewhere
        context.Done(true);
    }
}
```

Additionally, I want to use a scorable to handle certain global events such as asking for help or switching to a different section of my bot's functionality. However, in some cases such as asking for help, the user exchange several messages within the Scorable (answering prompts which triage the user to the right information, etc), which may push the last question far back in the conversation.

Because of these considerations, in a case where the user receives the "What is your name?" question but then hits a Scorable, I would like to reprompt the question after the context is returned to my ExampleDialog. In my real world scenario, the question may be one of many dynamic questions, so it can't be hard-coded in the Scorable before returning. Is there any way to define logic to execute when the context returns, similar to how the StartAsync task runs when context initially enters the new dialog?